# how to create charts in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts

How to create Charts in vb.net. Is it possible to have a chart like this  without any additional components ? If yes then how ?

[image]

Using this VS component for real time manipulation

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I can't see the picture (stupid internet blocker) but you should look into the [Microsoft Charting Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx) which work with both Windows Forms and ASP.Net.

The chart controls are shipped with the .Net framework 4.0 and above, or you can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en) 
the chart controls for the .Net framework version 3.5.

**Update:** Oooh, now I can see the pretty picture - the Microsoft Charting Controls can definitely do this.

Comment: This is the only way,
Microsoft released it separatly, but its very simple to understand.
If you stuck somewhere,feel free to ask

Comment: You mean I can't use the Chart component in the tool box for real time manipulation ?

Comment: @Failed_Noob I'm not sure, I've only really used them in web applications where they are images and can't be changed real-time.

Comment: @Kragen can you provide me a link to some tutorial on Microsoft Charting Controls

Comment: @Failed_Noob Sorry I don't know of any - the best I could do is linking you to some Google hits - there are definitely tutorials out there though - try searching for "Microsoft Charting Controls" and see what you find.

Comment: I am already using VS2010(.net 4) where can I find this Microsoft Charting Controls. I can't find them in components section.

Comment: @Failed_Noob Are you targeting the .Net Framework version 4.0?  If not they you will need to download them from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en), if they are installed there should be an item in the toolbar, which will automatically add the required references when you drag a control onto the form.